# Формат данных в csv-файле для Jenkins Plot Plugin

Tags: jenkins

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком формате должны быть данные в csv-файле для plot plugin'а?

Comment: Перед публикацией вопросы вы пользовались поиском?

Comment: @GrayHoax , пользовался, нужного результата не обнаружил, отчего и решил задать вопрос. Буду признателен если скинете ссылку на решенный аналогичный вопрос.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные в csv-файле должны быть в формате CSV файла - значения, разделенные запятыми. В первой строке - названия рядов данных, во второй - сами значения, например:

```
Параметр1,Параметр2,Параметр3,Параметр4
1035,12.1,0,-102
```

Plot Plugin будет вычитывать эти значения по всем билдам и рисовать вам графички.

Comment: Спасибо! В общем то, в таком формате и формировал файл с данными. Проблема оказалась в некорректном расположении, хотя jenkins и не ругался.